# When did Robert Frost write "Two Tramps in Mud Time"?

Tags: poetry, textual-history, robert-frost

Googling the poem, and utilizing Wikipedia, I could not find the answer to my question. The book I own ("101 Great American Poems") which contains the poem also does not give the year of its creation - it gives the birth and death years of the featured poets, but not the publication year of the specific poems.

Does anyone know? Or better yet (because I have this question about many poems), how can I find out when a particular poem was written?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wikipedia's [List of poems by Robert Frost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poems_by_Robert_Fros) includes it in a collection published in 1937. [*Robert Frost and the New England Renaissance* by George Monteiro](https://muse.jhu.edu/book/37431#76-81) claims:

> "Two Tramps in Mud Time" was first published in 1934. At the time Frost
>   remarked that he considered the poem to be "against having hobbies."

So, presumably it was written in (or before) 1934.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm very convinced by this. It's certainly not unprecedented for poets to write something and then put it away for a while, publishing it years later alone or when there's enough material for a collection or anthology.

Comment: True; though not a poet, Twain wrote "Huck Finn" from 1876-1884, off-and-on, shelving it several times, and almost gave it the old heave-ho once.